# How to create bash script that modifies .bashrc and have changes take effect in current session?

Tags: bash

I have an 'install' script which adds an alias to .bashrc (for example).
I want the change to take effect immediately after running the script (as if I manually did: `source .bashrc` after running the script).

The example script install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Do other stuff ...
echo "alias myalias='echo hello'" >> /root/.bashrc
```

Comment: Note: I want to execute (not source) the install script.

Comment: Unix doesn't work like that. Your changes won't toke effect in current shell.

Comment: Why can't you source it?

Comment: "I want to execute (not source) the install script." -- Sourcing *is* executing, with the difference being that sourcing makes the script execute in *this* process, whereas it would normally execute in a *new* process. You want the install script to have effect on *this* process, you need to source it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Now I understand that what I wanted is impossible. I need to source the file - which solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

From `man bash`, section SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS:

> `source filename [arguments]`
>
> Read  and  execute  commands  from filename in the current shell environment and return the exit status of the last command executed from filename. If filename does not contain a slash, filenames in PATH are used to find the directory containing filename. The file searched for in PATH need not be executable. [...]

You either have to...

- `source ~/.bashrc` from the process that called your `install.sh`, *or*
- have a `source ~/.bashrc` in your `install.sh`, **and** call it with `source install.sh`.

As soon as you have "just" called `install.sh`, that spawned a new shell process, and everything `install.sh` *can* do will affect *that* process only, not your current shell process. This is a security feature of the shell. If you want a script to affect your *current* process, you have to give it explicit permission to do so (via `source`).

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. The script is executed in a separate shell. It has no effect on the current shell from which the script was run.

Comment: If I've understood what he wants to do, he wants the changes to take effect _outside_ the script, meaning he has to run his script using `source` as well. Might want to make note of that.

Comment: @Eden: Expanded the answer.